# Exposing a web site through web services

Tags: java, spring, selenium, automation, java-service-wrapper

I know what I am asking is somehow weird. There is a web application (which we don't have access to its source code), and we want to expose a few of its features as web services.

I was thinking to use something like Selenium WebDriver, so I simulate web clicks on the application according to the web service request.

I want to know whether this is a better solution or pattern to do this.

I shall mention that the application is written using Java, Spring MVC (it is not SPA) and Spring Security. And there is a CAS server providing SSO.

Comment: JSoup could be an option. Just to send requests and parse responses

Comment: I tried that, but I couldn't login to application using that, it uses CAS and Spring Security for authentication.

Comment: Did you search the web?  I found [this](http://scraping.pro/how-to-use-selenium-webdriver-with-java/) rather easily.  If this doesn't address your problem can you please state what is different?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 As I said I am aware of Selenium, but the problem is the resulting web service will not be so efficient. Consider that I shall simulate logging in to system, navigating to proper menu, and then submitting proper data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do something similar to access web banking on behalf of a user, scrape his account data and obtain a credit score. In most cases, we have managed to reverse-engineer mobile apps and sniff traffic to use undocumented APIs. In others, we have to fall back to web scraping.

You can have two other types of applications to scrape:

- Data is essentially the same for any user, like product listings in Amazon
- Data is specific to each user, like in a banking app.

In the firs case, you could have your scraper running and populating a local database and use your local data to provide the web service. In the later case, you cannot do that and you need to scrape the site on user's request.

I understand from your explanation that you are in this later case.

When web scraping you can find really difficult web apps:

- Some may require you to send data from previous requests to the next
- Others render most data on the client with JavaScript

If any of these two is your case, Selenium will make your implementation easier though not performant.

Implementing the first without selenium will require you to do lots of trial an error to get the thing working because you will be simulating the requests and you will need to know what data is expected from the client. Whereas if you use selenium you will be executing the same interactions that you do with the browser and hence sending the expected data.
Implementing the second case requires your scraper to support JavaScript. AFAIK best support is provided by selenium. [HtmlUnit](http://resthooks.org/) claims to provide fair support, and I think JSoup provides no support to JavaScript.

Finally, if your solution takes too much time you can mitigate the problem providing your web service with a notification mechanism, similar to Webhooks or [Resthooks](http://resthooks.org/):

1. A client of your web service would make a request for data providing a URI they would like to get notified when the results are ready.
2. Your service would respond immediatly with an id of the request and start scraping the necessary info in the background.
3. If you use skinny payload model, when the scraping is done, you store the response in your data store with an id identifying the original request. This response will be exposed as a resource.
4. You would execute an HTTP`POST` on the URI provided by the client. In the body of the request you would add the URI of the response resource.
5. The client can now `GET` the response resource and because the request and response have the same id, the client can correlate both.

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunately the application uses Spring Web Flow (Although most of its uses cases are not flow based!), clicking most of the links creates a new flow with a new flow id.

Comment: Why is that a problem and in respect to which of the possible solutions provided?  can you elaborate further?

Comment: Well the applications is on a private network, and shall be exposed through some web-services to internet. Being on a private network doesn't allow me to use some internet cloud based solutions. I shall host all the robots (or anything) on that private network. I'll try HtmlUnit to find out if it is okay with application JavaScripts or not.

Comment: Your last solutions seems nice. I shall give it a try now.

Comment: Maybe a miscommunication but none of the possibilities I commented include a SaaS or cloud service. Resthooks is just a proposal, spec, on how to do async communications in rest services. It is not a solution.

Comment: I consider your answer the best and most relevant answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to implement it. In my opinion Selenium/PhantomJS is not the best option as if the web is properly designed, you can interact with it only using the provided HTML or even some API rather than needing all the CSS, and execute the javascript async requests. As your page is not SPA it's quite likely that an "API" already exists in form of GET/POST requests and you might be lucky enough that there's no CSRF protection.

First of all, you need to solve the authentication against the CAS. There are multiple types of authentication in oAuth, but you should get an API token that enables you access to the application. This token should be added in form of HTTP Header or Cookie in every single request. Ideally this token shouldn't expire, otherwise you'll need to implement a re-authentication logic in your app.

Once the authentication part is resolved, you'll need quite a lot of patience, open the target website with the web inspector of your preferred web browser and go to the Network panel and execute the actions that you want to run programmatically. There you'll find your request with all the headers and content and the response.
That's what you need to code. There are plenty of libraries to achieve that in Java. You can have a look at `Jsop` if you need to parse HTML, but to run plain GET/POST requests, go for `RestTemplate` (in Spring) or `JAX-RS/Jersey 2 Client`.

You might consider implementing a cache layer to increase performance if the result of the query is maintained over the time, or you can assume that in, let's say 5 minutes, the response will be the same to the same query.

You can create your app in your favourite language/framework. I'd recommend to start with `SpringBoot + MVC + DevTools`. That'd contain all you need + Jsoup if you need to parse some HTML. Later on you can add the cache provider if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium isn't a best way to consume webservices. Selenium is preferably an automation tool largely used for testing the applications.
Assuming the services are already developed, the first thing we need to do is authenticate user request.
This can be done by adding a HttpHeader with key as "Authorization" and value as "Basic "+ Base64Encode(username+":"+password)

If the user is valid (Users login credentials match with credentials in server) then generate a unique token, store the token in server by mapping with the user Id and 
set the same token in the response header or create a cookie containing token.
By doing this we can avoid validating credentials for the following requests form the same user by just looking for the token in the response header or cookie.
If the services are designed to chcek login every time the "Authorization" header needs to be set in request every time when the request is made.

Comment: As I mentioned I need an automation tool, because the legacy system does not provided web-services, it is an existing web application. And I want to expose some of its functionality as web services.

Comment: Amir Pashazadeh, I understood your problem. I think the only solution is developing web services by getting access to the source code. Selenium could be in appropriate option because the purpose of the tool doesn't support your need.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a lot of overhead using a `webdriver` but it depends on what you really want to achieve. With the info you provided I would rather go with a `restTemplate` implementation sending the appropriate http messages to the existing webapp, wrap it with a nice `@service` layer and build your web service (rest or soap) on top of it.

The authentication is a matter of configuration, you can pack this in a microservice with `@EnableOAuth2Sso` and your `restTemplate` bean, thanks to spring boot, will handle the underlining auth part for you.

Answer (score 0):

May be overkill..... But RPA? http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/review-automation-anywhere-enterprise